# Is there something that iBeacon offers that can't be done on iOS 6 using Core Bluetooth?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, ios7, core-bluetooth, ibeacon

I've been starting to read about the above and on BLE devices in general and trying to find the differences between those 2 frameworks. Is there something that the iBeacon API offers beside the option to use `startMonitoringForRegion` with `CLBeaconRegion` (which will basically "wake up" or notify the app that you're in range)?

To my understanding on iPhone 4S and up I can get a list of BLE devices and check their signal strength on iOS 6 sure, i't will not be as simple as the API for ranging but still, am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the CoreLocation APIs allow you to see iBeacon devices where CoreBluetooth does not.  See my in depth discussion of this here:  http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/10/21/corebluetooth-doesnt-let-you-see-ibeacons.html

This may not matter if you want to roll your own Bluetooth LE devices that are fully visible by CoreBluetooth.  But such devices are somewhat more complex and more power-hungry.  iBeacons by contrast are transmit only and send a minimal amount of data.

The bottom line is that if you want your app to see standard iBeacons, CoreBluetooth simply will not do the job.